# How to solve the following equation including some cross-products?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

Let $a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and $(w)_{\mathsf{x}}$ denotes the skew matrix associated with the cross product with a three dimensional vector, i.e., for $w,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$, we have $(w)_{\mathsf{x}}y = w \times y$.

Now, consider the following equation:

$$
\square = -(a - b - c)_{\mathsf{x}}(I + (d)_{\mathsf{x}}) + (I + (d)_{\mathsf{x}})(a - e)_{\mathsf{x}}
$$

where $I \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ is an identity matrix. Also, from the problem under investigation, $g = e - b$. I've tried a few times to expand this equation to get the answer provided by the author of the paper. Any help will be appreciated. The expected answer, assuming it is correct, is:

$$
\square = (-(a - g)_{\mathsf{x}} d - g + c)_{\mathsf{x}}
$$

**Edit 1:** Below it is what I did so far. I know that $(a)_{\mathsf{x}}(b)_{\mathsf{x}} - (b)_{\mathsf{x}}(a)_{\mathsf{x}} = (a \times b)_{\mathsf{x}} = (a)_{\mathsf{x}}b$. However, I didn't find properties to expand the red part.:

\begin{align}
\square &= -(a - b - c)_{\mathsf{x}} -(a - b - c)_{\mathsf{x}} (d)_{\mathsf{x}} + (a-e)_{\mathsf{x}} + (d)_{\mathsf{x}}(a-e)_{\mathsf{x}} \\
\square &= (-a + b + c +a -e)_{\mathsf{x}} -(a - b - c)_{\mathsf{x}} (d)_{\mathsf{x}} + (d)_{\mathsf{x}}(a-e)_{\mathsf{x}}\\
\square &= (b+c-e)_{\mathsf{x}} -(a - b - c)_{\mathsf{x}} (d)_{\mathsf{x}} + (d)_{\mathsf{x}}(a-e)_{\mathsf{x}}\\
\square &= (-g+c)_{\mathsf{x}} \color{red}{-(a - b - c)_{\mathsf{x}} (d)_{\mathsf{x}} + (d)_{\mathsf{x}}(a-e)_{\mathsf{x}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Hint: look up an expression for $u\times(v\times w)$ as a linear combination of $v,\,w$.

Comment: I've found $u \times (v \times w) = (u \cdot w)v - (u \cdot v) w$, but I didn't get the idea @J.G.

Comment: Hint $2$: $\square$ is a linear combination of matrices of the form $v_\times$ and $u_\times v_\times$, so $\square w$ is a linear combination of expressions of the form $v\times w$ and $u\times(v\times w)$. Now simplify the matrix $M$ for which the result is $Mw$. You should be able to prove with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) that $u_\times v_\times=vu^T-(u\cdot v)I$, if I haven't miscalculated.

Comment: I edited my question showing what I did so far, I couldn't find a place where I can use your hints @J.G.